# Is it possible for a bathroom countertop to be held up by angle brackets

Tags: bathroom, brackets, vanity

We're remodeling the bathroom and want to get the countertop put in.  Instead of building a vanity cabinet, we want to have a floating countertop (quartz).

We found the piece we're interested in, and we were told it's about 200 pounds. They said that we must have the location for the slab to be placed ready when they come out.

I've looked at solutions, and it seems angle brackets are the way to go. We found some rated for 500 pounds, and can put four of them connected to the studs to hold up the countertop + sinks.  This would be surrounded on three of the four sides.

Questions:

- Is this the correct route to go?
- Do we have an alternatives that I should look at?
- What's a good brand/product for angle brackets for this use?

Thanks!

Comment: this is unclear ... `This would be surrounded on three of the four sides.`

Comment: Sorry. What I meant is the countertop would be surrounded by three walls. And more info, we're thinking of having two angle brackets on the back side and one on each of the sides. So a total of 4 angle brackets holding it up.

Comment: What kind of length/width are we talking about here? You might (depends on attachment points) be able to get away with ledgers.

Comment: Sorry, thought I included that.

72" width, 20" depth double vanity.

Comment: And by ledger board you mean something like this? http://www.mudbetweenmytoes.com/laundry-room-countertop/

Comment: That is exactly what I meant by ledger board... however, at 6' wide, I wouldn't go that route. (Ledgers on the sides, maybe, but good brackets to support the middle.)

Comment: And while this site frowns on shopping advice (as it is fleeting), google 'fastcap speedbrace'.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion and information.  If you'd like to make a answer, I will mark it as solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a 6' wide slab, brackets are the right choice. In my ideal world, there would be at least 2 from the back wall, equally spaced, as well as ledgers on the sides. Be sure the brackets and ledgers are well attached to studs.

Stone/quartz/etc will often have plywood underneath to support the slab. Talk to your vendor about who is providing it, if it's necessary. If it's you, ask what thickness they want. (This-all assumes a built-up nosing.)

Lots of possibilities for brackets, but if you can't find anything locally, google 'fastcap speedbrace'.